# How to improve the algorithm for the Max Common Array Slice?

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

I was asked to take a HackerRank code test, and the exercise I was asked is the Max Common Array Slice. The problem goes as follows:

> You are given a sequence of n integers a0, a1, . . . , an−1 and the
>   task is to find the maximum slice of the array which contains no more
>   than two different numbers.
>
> Input 1 :
>
> [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 6, 2, 1, 8]
>
> Result 1 : Answer is 10 because the array slice of (0, 9) is the
>   largest slice of the array with no more than two different numbers.
>
> - There are 10 items in this slice which are "1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2".
> - 2 different numbers for this slice are 1 and 2.
>
> Input 2:
>
> [53, 800, 0, 0, 0, 356, 8988, 1, 1]
>
> Result 2: Answer is 4 because the slice of (1, 4) is the largest slice
>   of the array with no more than two different numbers. The slice (2, 5)
>   would also be valid and would still give a result of 4.
>
> - There are 4 items in this slice which are "800,0,0,0".
> - 2 different numbers for this slice are 800 and 0.
>
> Maximum common array slice of the array which contains no more than
>   two different numbers implementation in Java takes a comma delimited
>   array of numbers from STDIN and the output is written back to console.

The implementation I provide (below) works, however 3 test cases timeout in HR. Clearly, HR hides the test cases, so I could not see exactly the conditions the timeout was triggered or even the length of the timeout.
I'm not surprised of the timeout, though, given the asymptotic complexity of my solution. But my question is: how could my solution be improved?

Thanks in advance to all those that will help!

```
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.*;

public class Solution {
    public static void main(String args[] ) throws Exception {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String line = br.readLine();
        List<Integer> inputSequence = parseIntegerSequence(line);
        int largestSliceSize = calculateLargestSlice(inputSequence);

        System.out.println(largestSliceSize);
    }

    private static List<Integer> parseIntegerSequence(String input) {
        if (input == null)
            return new ArrayList();

        return Arrays.asList(input.split("\\s*,\\s*"))
                .stream()
                .filter(item -> item.matches("^\\s*-?[0-9]+\\s*$"))
                .map(item -> Integer.parseInt(item))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    private static int calculateLargestSlice(List<Integer> inputSequence) {

        Map<Integer, Integer> temporaryMap = new HashMap<>();

        int result = 0;
        int startIndex = 0;
        int uniqueItemCount = 0;

        Integer[] array = inputSequence.toArray(new Integer[inputSequence.size()]);

        while (startIndex < array.length) { // loop over the entire input sequence
            temporaryMap.put(array[startIndex], startIndex);
            uniqueItemCount++;

            for (int j = startIndex + 1; j < array.length; j++) {
                if (temporaryMap.get(array[j]) == null) {
                    if (uniqueItemCount != 2) {
                        temporaryMap.put(array[j], j);

                        uniqueItemCount++;
                        if (j == array.length - 1) {
                            result = Math.max(result, j - startIndex + 1);
                            startIndex = array.length;
                            break;
                        }
                    } else {
                        result = Math.max(result, j - startIndex);
                        int item = array[j-1];
                        int firstFoundIndex = 0;
                        for( int k=j-1; k>=0; k-- )
                        {
                            if( array[k] != item )
                            {
                                firstFoundIndex = k+1;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                        startIndex = firstFoundIndex;
                        temporaryMap.clear();
                        uniqueItemCount = 0;
                        break;
                    }
                } else if (temporaryMap.get(array[j]) != null) {
                    if (j == array.length - 1) {
                        result = Math.max(result, j - startIndex + 1);
                        startIndex = array.length;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please explain your algorithm in simple psuedo-code language.

Comment: This question is more suitable for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: just a two pointer technique `O(n)` probem

Comment: @Yerken I'd be interested in a pointer at the solution...

Comment: I am not familiar with Java, but i can provide c++ or python solution if u want

Comment: Thanks @Yerken. I think it'd be ok just to describe the solution you've got in mind, the one above does use two pointers but there is an internal loop (which I need in order to understand where to restart computation once a suitable interval was found) that I feel could be avoided...

Answer (score 0):

This is my answer in Java and it passed all the HackerRank test cases. Please feel free to comment if you find something wrong.

```
public static int maxCommonArraySlice(List<Integer> inputSequence) {
    if(inputSequence.size() < 2) return inputSequence.size(); // I'm doubting this line should be <= 2

    List<Integer> twoInts = new LinkedList<>();
    twoInts.add(inputSequence.get(0));
    int start = 0;
    int end = inputSequence.size();
    int count = 0;
    int max_length = 0;

    while(start < end) {
        if(twoInts.contains(inputSequence.get(start))) {
            count++;
            start++;
        }
        else if(twoInts.size() == 1) {
                twoInts.add(inputSequence.get(start));
        }
        else {  // twoInts.size() is 2
                count = 0;
                start--;
                twoInts.set(0, inputSequence.get(start));
                twoInts.set(1, inputSequence.get(start + 1));
        }

        if(count > max_length) {
            max_length = count;
        }
    }
    return max_length;

}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<Integer> input = new LinkedList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(53,800,0,0,0,356,8988,1,1));
    System.out.println(maxCommonArraySlice(input));

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this would work:

```
public int solution(int[] arr) {
    int lastSeen = -1;
    int secondLastSeen = -1;
    int lbs = 0;
    int tempCount = 0;
    int lastSeenNumberRepeatedCount = 0;

    for (int current : arr) {
        if (current == lastSeen || current == secondLastSeen) {
            tempCount ++;
        } else {
            // if the current number is not in our read list it means new series has started, tempCounter value in this case will be
            // how many times lastSeen number repeated before this new number encountered + 1 for current number.
            tempCount = lastSeenNumberRepeatedCount + 1;
        }

        if (current == lastSeen) {
            lastSeenNumberRepeatedCount++;
        } else {
            lastSeenNumberRepeatedCount = 1;

            secondLastSeen = lastSeen;
            lastSeen = current;
        }

        lbs = Math.max(tempCount, lbs);
    }
    return lbs;
}
```

[Reference](https://javabypatel.blogspot.com/2020/09/find-longest-length-bi-valued-slice-in-array-in-java.html)

Answer (score -1):

This is a python solution, as per requested by OP

```
def solution(arr):
    if (len(arr) <= 2): print arr 
    lres = 0 
    rres = 0
    l = 0
    r = 1 
    last = arr[1]
    prev = arr[0]
    while(r <= len(arr)-1):
        if prev != last:
            if arr[r] == prev:
                prev = last
                last = arr[r]               
            elif arr[r] != last:
                l = r-1
                while(arr[l-1] == last):
                    l -= 1
                last = arr[r] 
                prev = arr[r-1]             
        else:
            if arr[r] != prev:
                last = arr[r]
        if r - l > rres-lres:
            rres = r
            lres = l
        r += 1
    print arr[lres:rres+1]
```

For current segment let's say that `last` is the last value added and `prev` is the second distinct value in the segment. (initially they might be equal).

Let's keep to pointers `l` and `r` to left and right ends of the current segment with at most two distinct elements. And let's say we consider element `arr[r]`.
If current segment `[l,r-1]` contains only one distinct element, we can safely add `arr[r]`, with possibly updating `last` and `prev`. 
Now if `arr[r]` equals to `last`, then we don't need to do anything. If `arr[r]` equals to `prev`, we need to swap `prev` and `last`. If it equals to neither of those two, we need to update `l` left pointer, by tracing back from `r-1` until we find an element which is not equal to  `last`, then update `last` and `prev`.

Comment: Thanks @yerken. I tried migrating your algorithm to Java and tried it with the inputs from my original message. It does not seem to terminate. It seems to work for short arrays, but for instance with the first input shown in my initial message it does not seem to terminate in decent time. Perhaps it is my Java migration, but can you please elaborate more on the approach that the algorithm uses?

Comment: I tried it with the the python code and it seems to work correctly.  Make sure u migrated the code correctly, check the indexes are assigned and changed correctly.

Comment: https://ideone.com/pbVxlX published the whole code, you can modify the input on this platform

Comment: Thanks @Yerken, i think there is a misunderstanding. What your algorithm does is not what the problem above asks, please check the description above properly specifically on input and output.

Comment: sorry, the only difference i can see is the input format, the output format in the code I provided is the actual maximum slice, u can extract its size or print format as u find suitable

Comment: otherwise please provide an input where the code above gives wrong output :)

Comment: Thanks Yerken. Actually the specs do not agree with your thoughts:

With an input of [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 6, 2, 1, 8]

Result 1 : Answer is 10 because the array slice of (0, 9) is the largest slice of the array with no more than two different numbers.

There are 10 items in this slice which are "1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2".
2 different numbers for this slice are 1 and 2.

If I had to wear my reviewer's hat, your algorithm would be incorrect because:
- the specs require printing an index (10) rather the interval, and
- the interval should be [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118387/discussion-between-yerken-and-diferdin).